# VBA Excel - checking cell contents before writing

Tags: excel, vba

I'm brand-spanking new to VBA and having trouble with the output from this UserForm.

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()
Dim RowCount As Long
```

...

```
RowCount = Worksheets("Assignments").Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Assignments").Range("A3")
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Me.txtReportAddress.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.cmbCityCounty.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Me.txtFee.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = Me.txtDate.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 4).Value = Me.cmbPropertyType.Value
    .Offset(RowCount, 5).Value = Me.txtComments.Value
End With
```

It gives the proper output, but any subsequent entries overwrite past entires.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with 'CurrentRegion' but it looks like you are counting the rows and then over-writing the last row; you count 5 rows then write into the 5th row which is the last row containing data, is it as simple as adding 1 to the RowCount?

Alternatively what I have done with things like this is:

```
RowCount = Application.CountA(Worksheets("Assignments").Columns("A"))
    ' Depending on what is in rows 1 and 2 of colomn A you may need to adjust
    ' ie if row 2 is blank then the count will be 1 higher than needed so you 
    ' can adjust accordingly
Dim c as Range
Set c = Worksheets("Assignments").Range("A" & RowCount + 1)
With c
    .value = Me.txtReportAddress.Value
    .Offset(0,1).Value... etc as per your code
```

Hope this answers your question.